# Can I have same UV for 2 different faces?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Pardon me if I asked my question wrong.

Is it possible to have the selected UV of this object be unwrapped only once and assigned to the back of the mesh since it's the same? I need to fit the UV's of the WHOLE object in one UV since I will be painting it in Blender, and I don't want to have to have to paint the back of the objects since it's supposed to be the same.
[image]

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Mirror modifier or duplicating the object, scaling and using transfer data modifier might work.

Comment: You can also use the Project from View option, the back and front UVs will overlap

Comment: Which option would be the most optimized one for a game asset?

Comment: Project from View is OK, it will make the selected faces overlap, it seems like this is what you want? Then you can reorganize them the way you want in the UV Editor, and paint. I guess there are no problem for overlapping UVs in game engines?